# SQL query for MYSQL for BETWEEN dates is not inclusive of the specified range?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to create an SQL statement for MYSQL to retrieve records that fall between a date range.  I would like the records to come back that includes the two dates that specify the range.  At the moment this is not happening.  Please can someone advise?

MY SQL-PHP:

```
 $fromDate = '21-SEP-2018';
 $toDate = '29-SEP-2018';

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE zapDocUserId='$USER_ID' AND dateUpload BETWEEN \"$fromDate\" AND \"$toDate\" ORDER BY dateUpload DESC";
 $result = $mysqli -> query($sql);
```

The records that I get back do not include ones with dates 21-SEP-2018 and  29-SEP-2018.  I would like it to be included.

Comment: `'21-SEP-2018'` is not MySQL date format. What is the datatype for your `dateUpload` column ? I suspect that it is string type.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `between` for dates.  The problem is the time component.  Aaron Bertrand has a good blog about this ([What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)).  Although geared to SQL Server, it applies to any database.

You seem to want:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE zapDocUserId = '$USER_ID' AND
     dateUpload >= '$fromDate' AND 
      dateUpload < '$toDate' + interval 1 day
ORDER BY dateUpload DESC;
```

Of course, this doesn't fix your date format.  That is a different matter.  But, you shouldn't merely fix the date format.  You should learn how to pass parameters into queries, so the query is getting the right type to begin with.  With placeholders, the query would look more like:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE zapDocUserId = ? AND
     dateUpload >= ? AND 
      dateUpload < ? + interval 1 day
ORDER BY dateUpload DESC;
```

Comment: very hellpful answer, thank you very much, even in 2021!

Answer (score 2):

Your date literals are not valid in MySQL (or many other flavors of SQL).  If you use a valid format, the query should work.  Also, you should really be using prepared statements in your PHP code.  Taking both of these into account, the following should work:

```
$fromDate = '2018-09-21';
$toDate = '2018-09-29';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE zapDocUserId = ? AND dateUpload BETWEEN ? AND ? ";
$sql .= "ORDER BY dateUpload DESC";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('iss', $USER_ID, $fromDate, $toDate);
$stmt->execute();
```

This assumes that your `dateUpload` column is a proper date type column.  If `dateUpload` is actually *text*, and you are storing your dates as e.g. `21-SEP-2018`, then you would also have to make a call to `STR_TO_DATE` to convert the dates in your table as well:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE zapDocUserId = ? AND ";
$sql .= "STR_TO_DATE(dateUpload, '%d-%b-%Y') BETWEEN ? AND ? ";
$sql .= "ORDER BY dateUpload DESC";
```

[See here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html) to read more about the rules for MySQL date and time literals.

Comment: Doesn't RDB support those dates?

Comment: @jarlh Are you just messing with me or is that an actual question?

Comment: It was just a polite remark that those dates exist in the SQL world.

Comment: @jarlh Tim's point is that anything you put in a VARCHAR column is nothing but text as long as MySQL is concerned. You can write code to parse such text and convert it to other types (integers, decimals, dates...) as long as the text is parseable but in general terms it's manual work that needs to be done explicitly.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, totally agree.

Comment: +1 for showing Prepared statements based approach. I think you would need to explicitly mention this in answer, so that OP takes note.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I updated my answer, thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to solve your problem is to use the `CAST(<field> AS DATE)` clause. That will remove the timing component from the query:

```
$fromDate = '2018-09-21';
$toDate = '2018-09-29';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE zapDocUserId = ? AND CAST(dateUpload AS DATE) BETWEEN ? AND ? ";
$sql .= "ORDER BY dateUpload DESC";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('iss', $USER_ID, $fromDate, $toDate);
$stmt->execute();
```

In this example `CAST(dateUpload AS DATE)` —  the way to remove the time component from the comparison and use a date only.

Comment: It gives me a correct starting row but the last row is 1 day behind